# Regular expression (PCRE) for URL matching

Tags: php, regex, url, pcre

The input: we get some plain text as input string and we have to highlighight all URLs there with `<a href={url}>{url></a>`.

For some time I've used regex taken from http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/, which I modified several times, but it's built for another issue - to check whether the whole input string is an URL or no.

So, what regex do you use in such issues?

**UPD**: it would be nice if answers were related to php :-[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a couple of modules available on CPAN:

- [URI::Find](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find/lib/URI/Find.pm)
- [URI::Find::Schemeless](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find/lib/URI/Find/Schemeless.pm)

where the latter is a little more forgiving. The regular expressions are available in the source code ([the latter's](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MSCHWERN/URI-Find-20100505/lib/URI/Find/Schemeless.pm), for example).

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use URI::Find::Schemeless;

my $text = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms is swell!\n";

URI::Find::Schemeless
  ->new(sub { qq[<a href="$_[0]">$_[0]</a>] })
  ->find(\$text);

print $text;
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms">http://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms</a> is swell!
```

Answer (score 0):

For Perl, I usually use one of the modules defining common regex, `Regexp::Common::URI::*`. You might find a good regexp for you in the sources of those modules.

http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Regexp%3A%3ACommon%3A%3AURI&mode=module